# Delete a row from sqlite database table using id

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

This is how I created my database

```
 public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper
 {
public static final   String DATABASE_NAME="MyDatabase.db";
public static final  int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
//table name
public static final String TABLE_NAME_INFO="info";
    //column name
public static final String ID="_id";
public static final String COL_INFO_NAME="name";
public static final String COL_INFO_GEN="gender";
// creating table


   public static final String CREATE_TABLE="create table "+TABLE_NAME_INFO+" ("+"_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+COL_INFO_NAME+" text,"+COL_INFO_GEN+" text)";

public MyDatabase(Context context)
{
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
}


public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db , int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists "+TABLE_NAME_INFO);
}


}
```

Now I want to delete a item in list view when the _id is id of the list view.Like this

```
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
 MyDatabase helper= new MyDatabase(this);
 SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();

 db.delete(MyDatabase.TABLE_NAME_INFO,MyDatabase.ID+" = "+Integer.toString((int)id), null);
  }
```

But it does not work . Please suggest me a way to delete the row using _id.

Comment: You create a new database whenever the button is clicked ? Did you check that the id is read correctly ? Did you debug ? Did you add a message like : Log.v("MyApp", "Integer.toString((int)id)" to check the number is correct ? What have you already done ?

Comment: Everything is working correctly . My values are stored in database . The problem is I could not delete the row using _id column , although I performed a delete using COL_INFO_NAME column and it worked .But I want to delete using _id column.

Comment: You did not answer my questions

Comment: Also, I don't like the `MyDatabase helper= new MyDatabase(this);` there, you should not create the DB when something is clicked, because you will be creating a new one each time. Are you sure you are not checking another database ? You could add this to check if it's actually working or not:  `int result = db.delete(MyDatabase.TABLE_NAME_INFO,MyDatabase.ID+" = "+Integer.toString((int)id), null); Log.v("TAG", result);` This will print how many rows have been affected or edited, so if the number in the Logcat is not 0, it worked.

Comment: com.coolniks.datebase E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: _id    This is the error.

Answer (score -1):

To delete a row from that table use the following syntax...

```
 db.delete(MyDatabase.TABLE_NAME_INFO, MyDatabase.ID + " = ? ",
                        new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
```

It also has the benefit of prepared statements which prevents SQL injection.